# Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment | Debian 10

Tags: debian, android, graphics

I recently installed Debian 10. When I try to install Android Studio, I get this error :

```
No protocol specified

Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment

java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:134)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.updateFrameClass(AppUIUtil.java:172)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:113)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.lambda$start$0(PluginManager.java:76)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by changing user, I was trying to install Android Studio as a root. But when I opened a new terminal tab and I run the commands as a standard user, the installation launches with no errors.